# Vue - check if user is offline and then show div for a second once they come back online

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I currently am using a function on a timed loop to check if a user goes offline:

```
created() {
   setInterval(() => {
        this.checkOnline();
   }, 30000);
}
```

Method:

```
checkOnline(){
   this.onLine = navigator.onLine ? true : false;
}
```

Is there a way I can detect this without using the timer?

Secondly...

I am trying to show an 1 second alert to tell the user they are back online. When this.onLine is true, the div should be hidden. When it is false it should also be hidden, but when it goes from false to true I want to show the div for a second or so and then hide it again. I have tried this with a settimeout and using a watcher but neither give the desired effect.

**Edit:**

So one method that gets me there is:

```
 data() {
     return {
         onLine: navigator.onLine ? true : false,
     }
 }
```

then a watcher to show the back online message

```
watch: {
    onLine: function (val) {
        if(this.onLine === true){
            this.showBackOnline = true;
            setTimeout(()=>{ this.showBackOnline = false; }, 1000);
        }
    },
},
```

Is there a better way than a watcher to achieve this, other than using a dedicated notify plugin?

Comment: You need to use some kind of storage where you store the visit count like a cookie, HTML 5 localstorage or DBMS

Comment: What about mouse events? You can use one of them :). OR use [`ononline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/Online_and_offline_events) event

Comment: Why not using computed properties for `onLine`? It should be instant.

Answer (score 18):

*Is there a way I can detect this without using the timer?* **Yes**. By using the online offline event.

*Is there a better way than a watcher to achieve this, other than using a dedicated notify plugin?* I think the watcher is the most suitable method here.

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jacobgoh101/xz6e3705/4/

```
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        onLine: navigator.onLine,
        showBackOnline: false
    },
    methods: {
        updateOnlineStatus(e) {
            const {
                type
            } = e;
            this.onLine = type === 'online';
        }
    },
    watch: {
        onLine(v) {
            if (v) {
                this.showBackOnline = true;
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.showBackOnline = false;
                }, 1000);
            }
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        window.addEventListener('online', this.updateOnlineStatus);
        window.addEventListener('offline', this.updateOnlineStatus);
    },
    beforeDestroy() {
        window.removeEventListener('online', this.updateOnlineStatus);
        window.removeEventListener('offline', this.updateOnlineStatus);
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for this. So actually, I think that the `navigator.onLine` may actually fire as an event? This seems to change directly from true to false with the connection without any other code. I don't fully understand what this navigator.onLine function/event is but it seems to be doing the trick!

Answer (score 2):

you can handle this (update onLine status), just by set arrow function in event listener and set that varible true/false by listener.
window object has online/offline events and you don't need to watch for navigator.online value or set interval to check it. you can just set event listener for it and do something on callback method.
in below code i just change value of my 'isOnLine' variable value and in template show message by v-if directive to user about online/offline.

```
  data() {
    return {
      isOnLine:navigator.onLine
    }
  },
  mounted() {
     window.addEventListener('online', ()=>{this.isOnLine=true});
     window.addEventListener('offline', ()=>{this.isOnLine=false});
  },
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: plus don't forget to remove the listeners beforeDestroy() !!

Comment: Thank you @Tyler2P for your comment to remind me for more detail of my post. i edit my post and write more. i hopeful that it has complete detail